# "Not enough x observations" and "Not enough Y observations" error messages when performing t-test as part of code

Tags: r, bioconductor

noob here. I'm learning some basic sorting algorithms as part of a bioinformatics course and I'm running into a problem with a code I'm using. We learned how to write this in lab and it worked fine using the dataset we were given, but now I'm trying to apply it to the homework (we're allowed to get help with homework, I asked the TA for help too) dataset and I'm running into trouble. Any ideas what's going on here?

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("golubEsets")
a   
a
library(golubEsets) 

data(Golub_Merge)  
Golub_Merge

varLabels(Golub_Merge)
Golub_Merge.1<-Golub_Merge[,order(Golub_Merge$ALL.AML)]  
Golub_Merge.1$ALL.AML



Golub_Merge.sd<-apply(exprs(Golub_Merge.1), 1, sd)
Golub_Merge.new<-Golub_Merge.1 [Golub_Merge.sd>1, ]
Golub_Merge.new   

heatmap( cor(exprs(Golub_Merge.new)), Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, scale="none", labRow=Golub_Merge.new$ALL.AML, labCol= Golub_Merge.new$ALL.AML, RowSideColors= as.character(as.numeric(Golub_Merge.new$ALL.AML)), ColSideColors= as.character(as.numeric(Golub_Merge.new$ALL.AML)))
Golub_Merge$T.B.cell 


#classification analysis

bio<-which(Golub_Merge$ALL.AML %in% c("ALL", "AML"))  
isb<-grep("^B", as.character(Golub_Merge$T.B.cell))  
kp<-intersect(bio, isb)
Golub_Merge.2<-Golub_Merge[, kp]   
tmp<-Golub_Merge.2$ALL.AML == "ALL"
tmp<-ifelse(tmp, "ALL", "AML")
pData(Golub_Merge.2)$bcrabl<-factor(tmp) 
Golub_Merge.2$bcrabl

Golub_Merge.mean<-apply(exprs(Golub_Merge.2), 1, mean)
Golub_Merge.sd<-apply(exprs(Golub_Merge.2), 1,sd)
Golub_Merge.ML<-Golub_Merge.2[Golub_Merge.mean>=7 & Golub_Merge.sd>=0.3,]  


#training and testing set cross-validation

t.stat<-function(x, group)
{
    t.test(x[group=="ALL"], x[group=="AML"])$statistic
}
set.seed(12345)
train.index<-sample(ncol(Golub_Merge.ML), 38)
test.index<-setdiff(1:ncol(Golub_Merge.ML), train.index)
Golub_Merge.train<- Golub_Merge.ML[, train.index]
Golub_Merge.test<- Golub_Merge.ML[, test.index]
a<-apply(exprs(Golub_Merge.train), 1, t.stat,
```

And that's where the error comes up.

Sorry if this is a 'bad' question. I'm new to all this.

Comment: Please share the exact error messages also in your question, not only in the title.

Comment: I have run your code but do not get the same error as you do... The error I am receiving is: "Error in t.test(x[group == "ALL"], x[group == "AML"]) : 
  argument "group" is missing, with no default". Your last line of code is incomplete and so I just closed the parentheses to complete the `apply()` As I inspect your code it appears that to get it to run you need to pass the groups to the t.stat function.

Comment: I just inspected `Golub_Merge.train` and it only has one factor level in the `bcrabl` slot. This may be why you are having trouble...